# How to disable input type=text in javascript so that it can't be changed even by inspection

Tags: javascript

It is possible to disable input element by adding `disabled` attribute. However this can be removed by devtools that come with browsers. Is there any other way to deal with this so that devtools can't be used to enable it?

Comment: This isn't possible. The DOM inspector can do anything it likes to the DOM on the client side. If you're trying to secure your system, then you need to do it all server side with input sanitization, one-time tokens etc.

Comment: *"so that devtools can't be used to enable it"* - No.  The user can modify whatever they like in the developer tools.  There's no guarantee the client is even using your "page" or client-side code at all.  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: User should not be allowed to enter a value and it should be readonly for some cases.I think for such cases, server has to do the validation. –

Comment: Always recheck on the server. You can make it more difficult by adding styles and such, but in the end you can not prevent it. Yet, if the user is not supposed to enter a value, why create an `input` for it at all? Just use a not form element.

Comment: @user2599052: *"User should not be allowed to enter a value"* - Then server-side code should not accept a value for that data.  The user can do whatever they want **in their own browser**, but changing the page within their browser doesn't affect the server or the backing data at all.  It doesn't sound like there's an actual problem to be solved here.

Comment: its conditional and I would not like to change the elem type for this case

Comment: @user2599052: You don't have to change the element type.  Your UI can be whatever you want it to be.  If the user shouldn't be able to update the data on the server then don't update the data on the server.  Sorry, but it still sounds like there's no actual problem here, just some mistaken assumptions on your part regarding web pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. You should validate on the server side *everything* that comes from the client, because you can't trust the client at all. It's always possible to mess with the HTML/Javascript on the client side.